# Phonegap BUILD plugin for chromecast mirroring (iOS&Android)

Tags: cordova, plugins, phonegap-build, chromecast

I'm stucked to find a Phonegap BUILD (yes, it really needs to be compatible with this service) plugin that works properly.

I've tried a lot of plugins, but none of them seems to work. I really liked the ConnectSDK aproach, but phonegap build got an error at building, the error reported is:

(iOs)

> 'Error - The following 3rd-party plugin is causing the build to fail
>   and may need to be updated to a newer version:
>   cordova-plugin-connectsdk'

(Android)

> 'Oh geez. Your build failed. Click the "Log" button above to view the
>   compile log. If you need help diagnosing the issue, you can post to
>   the support forum with your App ID (please do a search first).'

I found an old issue in their Github reporting a similar but not equal case, and seems that they don't support the phonegap build service..

> "However, you won't be able to build using PhoneGap Build since it
>   requires a binary plugin, the closed-source Google Cast SDK plugin.
>   Currently PhoneGap Build does not support binary plugins."
>   at: https://github.com/ConnectSDK/Connect-SDK-Cordova-Plugin/issues/1

Does anyone already used a plugin that fit in this purpose ? (it could be separated plugin for each platform).

All kinds of help are welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you click the Log button next to a PhoneGap Build build, then search for "error", you may see what the exact error is. In my experience though, it's usually a compilation code issue that you'd have to fix manually - defeating the purpose of PG Build.

If the Google Cast SDK plugin isn't supported on PhoneGap Build, there's not much you can do, short of contacting Adobe.  Sounds like this is not ideal for you, but your best course of action is to build your project using [the Cordova CLI](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html#add-plugins). It'll take more effort than Build, but it's not too bad. Create a local "project", add the Cast and other plugins, and build for iOS/Android.